# About this mac → Storage not showing anything

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, mojave, storage

The storage information is not shown under About this mac → Storage, but the same is available in Disk Utility.

[image]

[image]

I tried to turn my MacBook off and on again, but to no avail.

I have a mid 2012 MacBook Pro with raid0 SSD storage running macOS Mojave.

Comment: Some of the following insight would be helpful: What version of Mojave are you running? Did this occur after or before you created your raid? What does it say in About this Mac > Overview > System Report > Hardware > Sata/SataExpress? Is there information available there?

Comment: I have the same problem. It has just occurred today. Disk utility seems fine. When I go to details, the storage shows up. Subtle eh?